# Disabling Button After First Click Ajax.BeginForm with Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Having an issue hiding/disabling the submit button with it also submitting the form. I have tried adding: `onclick="this.value='Submitting, Please Wait.'; this.disabled='disabled';"` into the input submit field which will disable the button but wont submit the form. I have tried placing this into the javascript portion also and it not working. I have tried things like this also:

```
$("#SignInButton").one('click', function (event) { 
  event.preventDefault(); 

  $(this).prop('disabled', true); 
});
```

I am at a loss because a lot of examples I am looking at are for html.beginform and this old form was set up with `Ajax.BeginForm`. Any insight on how to either just hide the button or disable the button with the code below would be much help!!

```html
<div id="LoginModal" style="display:none;padding:1rem;max-width:580px;">
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Accounts", 
    new AjaxOptions 
    { 
      HttpMethod = "POST", 
      OnSuccess = "OnSuccess", 
      OnFailure = "OnSuccess" 
    }))
    {
      <div>
          Other Form Data
          <div>
            @Html.Hidden("ItemID", Model.ItemID)
            <input type="submit" id="SignInButton" data-loading-text="Signing in" class="button success" value="Sign In" />
          </div>
      </div>
    }

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var ready;
      ready = function () {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
          'content': $('#LoginModal'),
          'onStart': function () { $("#LoginModal").css("display", "block"); },
          'onClosed': function () { $("#LoginModal").css("display", "none"); }
        });
      };

    $(document).ready(ready);
    $(document).on('page:load', ready);
  </script>
```

EDIT!!!!!

```
<div id="LoginModal" style="display:none;padding:1rem;max-width:580px;">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Accounts", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess", OnFailure = "OnSuccess" }))
{
    <h1>Sign In</h1>
    var displayLocalLogin = "";
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-error" })
    @Html.Sitecore().FormHandler()
    <div class="">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="internal">
                <div class="medium-12 columns">
                </div>
                <div class="medium-12 border-top columns">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="UserName">UserName <span class="required">*</span></label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="medium-12 columns">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Password">Password <span class="required">*</span></label>
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="medium-12 columns" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="medium-5 columns left">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                @Html.Hidden("ItemID", Model.ItemID)
                                <input type="submit" id="SignInButton" data-loading-text="Signing in" class="button success" value="Sign In">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @if (string.Equals(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableSalesForceLogin"], "true", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                displayLocalLogin = "displaynone";
                @Html.Partial("/salesforceloginpartial.cshtml")
            }
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#SignInButton").one('click', function (event) {
    $(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
});


//function OnSuccess(data) {
//  alert(data);
//  $('#LoginModal').parent.html(data).css("display", "block");
//  $("#LoginModal").css("display", "block");
//}

var ready;
ready = function () {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        'content': $('#LoginModal'),
        'onStart': function () { $("#LoginModal").css("display", "block"); },
        'onClosed': function () { $("#LoginModal").css("display", "none"); }
    });
};
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the button in the next event loop excecution by using `setTimeout(func, 0)`:

```
$("#SignInButton").one('click', function (event) { 
  setTimeout(function() { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $(this).prop('disabled', true); 
  }, 0); 
});
```

This will block the button right after the user click, but it will pass the first click.

Comment: Hey @beniamin H, The setTimeout actually does not work for me. I have tried this before. It just sits and nothing happens after clicking the button.

Comment: It strange as it should work - please take a look on this sample: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VqderQ?editors=1111

Comment: Yeah I know I have played with so many examples online. I have placed the whole file above if you want to look at the whole thing. I am not sure what else to try.

Comment: You should put `$("#SignInButton").one(...` inside `ready` function. DOM must be loaded to find add a listener to SignInButton.

Comment: Hey @Beniamin H, Placing that inside the ready function still does not work either. I tried taking out the timer portion also to test, which also did not work. Did not follow to the submit feature.

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit the form after disabling button.

Give to your form an id:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login",
                       "Accounts",  
                       new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess", OnFailure = "OnSuccess" },
                       new { id = "formId"}))
```

and then submit it by javascript:

```
$("#SignInButton").one('click', function (event) {
     event.preventDefault(); 
     $(this).prop('disabled', true);    //disable button
     $("#formId").submit();             //submit the form
 });
```

Comment: Hey @kurohige, calling that formId was giving me errors. The first iteration of my code did not have that formid. I tried adding it after looking at some other examples. That was giving me a "Could not invoke action method: Login. Controller".

Comment: @ImSobesBoosted then disable only the button(see update)

Comment: Yeah I tried this also. This just disables the button and sits. It never submits the form. I am at a loss.

Comment: @ImSobesBoosted Can you please add the outer html you have after page rendering?

Comment: I get this error when I go that route: Could not invoke action method: Login. Controller name: Sitecore. Controller type: Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreController

Comment: That's a different problem

Comment: Yeah I gave up. I decided to set a disabled button on top of the button after clicked. Something was acting weird. Thanks for all the help though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set the attribute disabled to "disabled" instead

```
  $(this).prop('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try to make use of ajaxStart and ajaxStop methods from jquery.

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

May be something like, in ajaxStart disable the button.